# Write file from BLOB mysql python

Tags: python, mysql, file, blob

I'm trying to get a file from a database and write it to disk. The file is stored as BLOB.

Now I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import MySQLdb

db2 = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                      user="root",
                      passwd="root",
                      db="digit")

cur = db2.cursor()
#get the name of the file
cur.execute("SELECT Name FROM ContentFiles WHERE ID=3")
nombre = cur.fetchone()
#open file and write into.
with open(nombre[0],"wb") as output_file:
    cur.execute("SELECT File FROM ContentFiles WHERE ID=3")
    ablob = cur.fetchone()
    output_file.write(ablob[0])
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks :)

I debugged and it gets the file and write it into disk, but when I open it shows an error saying:

```
Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x2f 0x39
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution, I needed to use the decode('base64') ... it was an easy problem :/

```
cur = db2.cursor()
#get the file
cur.execute("SELECT mimetype,File,Name FROM ContentFiles WHERE ContentID=10414")
archivo = cur.fetchone()

imagen = open(archivo[2],'wb')
imagen.write(archivo[1].decode('base64'))
imagen.close()
```